# Location services Unity to Xcode

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, geolocation

I'm literally banging my head against a wall with this one.

I am creating a location based game in Unity and following all instructions from a book. We have used the standard 'google map tile' script and 'GPS location services' script that Unity provide in standard assets.

Now, when I enter play mode everything looks great but when deploying to my iPhone then no map is being rendered... only the rubbish red question marks!

Furthermore my phone isn't even being asked to ALLOW LOCATION and when I go to location services for the build there is no option for ENABLE.

Is this a setting that needs to be turned on in Xcode prior to build perhaps for location enabling?

```
    public enum MapType
    {
        RoadMap,
        Satellite,
        Terrain,
        Hybrid
    }

    private const string GOOGLE_MAPS_URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";

    public int zoomLevel = 1;
    public MapType mapType = MapType.RoadMap;
    public int size = 640;
    public bool doubleResolution = true;

    public GPSLocationService gpsLocationService;

    public MapLocation worldCenterLocation;
    public MapLocation tileCenterLocation;

    public Vector2 TileOffset;
    public Vector2 TopLeftCorner;
    public Vector2 BottomRightCorner;

    private double lastGPSUpdate;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        RefreshMapTile ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (gpsLocationService != null &&
            gpsLocationService.IsServiceStarted && 
            lastGPSUpdate < gpsLocationService.Timestamp)
        {
            lastGPSUpdate = gpsLocationService.Timestamp;
            worldCenterLocation.Latitude = gpsLocationService.Latitude;
            worldCenterLocation.Longitude = gpsLocationService.Longitude;
            print("GoogleMapTile refreshing map texture");
            RefreshMapTile();
        }
    }

    public void RefreshMapTile() {

        StartCoroutine(_RefreshMapTile());
    }

    IEnumerator _RefreshMapTile ()
    {            
        tileCenterLocation.Latitude = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLatByPixels(worldCenterLocation.Latitude, (int)(size * 1 * TileOffset.y), zoomLevel);
        tileCenterLocation.Longitude = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLonByPixels(worldCenterLocation.Longitude, (int)(size * 1 * TileOffset.x), zoomLevel);

        var url = GOOGLE_MAPS_URL;
        var queryString = "";

        queryString += "center=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", tileCenterLocation.Latitude, tileCenterLocation.Longitude));
        queryString += "&zoom=" + zoomLevel.ToString ();
        queryString += "&size=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0}x{0}", size));
        queryString += "&scale=" + (doubleResolution ? "2" : "1");
        queryString += "&maptype=" + mapType.ToString ().ToLower ();
        queryString += "&format=" + "png";

        //styles
        queryString += "&style=element:geometry|invert_lightness:true|weight:3.1|hue:0x00ffd5";
        queryString += "&style=element:labels|visibility:off";

        var usingSensor = false;
```

## if MOBILE_INPUT

```
        usingSensor = Input.location.isEnabledByUser && Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running;
```

## endif

```
        queryString += "&sensor=" + (usingSensor ? "true" : "false");

        //set map bounds rect
        TopLeftCorner.x = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLonByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Longitude, -size, zoomLevel);
        TopLeftCorner.y = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLatByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Latitude, size, zoomLevel);

        BottomRightCorner.x = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLonByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Longitude, size, zoomLevel);
        BottomRightCorner.y = GoogleMapUtils.adjustLatByPixels(tileCenterLocation.Latitude, -size, zoomLevel);

        print(string.Format("Tile {0}x{1} requested with {2}", TileOffset.x, TileOffset.y, queryString));

        var req = new WWW(url + "?" + queryString);
        //var req = new WWW("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=50.917316,-114.080923&zoom=17&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:landscape.man_made|visibility:on|invert_lightness:true");
        yield return req;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
        print(string.Format("Tile {0}x{1} textured", TileOffset.x, TileOffset.y));
    }
}
```

}

Many thanks for your help

Carl

Comment: You need to post the code you are using to get the image, mention your Unity and iOS version. Also add the C# tag to get more people see your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however, its not a coding issue I have. My apologies for probably explaining it awfully. I am only really after an answer to whether or not there is a setting in Xcode that must be activated before testing location based games in the simulator. My map tiles will not render with my location (where as unity play mode is fine)

Comment: I understand your question. You are downloading images from Google Map server, and you  are seeing the red question mark instead of the image, right? If you don't post the code that's downloading the image, your Unity and iOS version you won't get an answer. Any answer you get would be "try this" and "try that". I answer question when I am sure about the cause of the problem. I can't tell without those information because there are many reasons this may happen.

Comment: Thanks again, hopefully now I have added the code it will become obvious for someone. I'm spending far too much time on this today :)